# why is logged undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, module

so I'm making a module that actually just got get a text with cheerio

but when I try it returns undefined

do you know what did I make wrong?

it supposed to send an object like

title: '',

id: '',

thumb: '',

episode: '',

uploaded_on: '',

day_updated: '',

link: ''

something.js

```
function abc() {
  let home = {};
  let ongoing = [];
  let complete = [];
  axios.get(baseUrl).then((response) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const element = $(".venz");

    let episode, uploaded_on, day_updated, thumb, title, link, id;
    element
      .children()
      .eq(0)
      .find("ul > li")
      .each(function () {
        $(this)
          .find(".thumb > a")
          .filter(function () {
            title = $(this).find(".thumbz > h2").text();
            thumb = $(this).find(".thumbz > img").attr("src");
            link = $(this).attr("href");
            id = link.replace(`${baseUrl}anime/`, "");
          });
        uploaded_on = $(this).find(".newnime").text();
        episode = $(this).find(".epz").text().replace(" ", "");
        day_updated = $(this).find(".epztipe").text().replace(" ", "");
        ongoing.push({
          title,
          id,
          thumb,
          episode,
          uploaded_on,
          day_updated,
          link,
        });

        home.ongoing = ongoing;
        return response;
      });
    // console.log(home)
    // return respon
    return response;
  });
}

module.exports = {
  home: abc,
};
```

index.js

```
const home = require("./something")
console.log(home.home())
```

Answer (score 0):

in your approach, you facing the issue of async code that is not fulfilled
and not return best approach will be to refactor your function to use async\await it will be easier for you (less return and handle the promise)
working example base your code style not using async/await :

file.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
function abc() {
    return axios.get('https://google.com').then((response) => {
      return response;
    });
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    home: abc,
  };
```

index.js

```
const asyncFunction = require('./file');
asyncFunction.home().then(res => console.log(res)) // waiting in the old fashion for promise to fulfill and console.log the result.
```

The second approach is better in my opinion (no callback hell..)

file.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
async function abc() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://google.com');
    return response;
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    home: abc,
  };
```

index.js

```
const asyncFunction = require('./file');
main();

async function main() {
    const results = await asyncFunction.home();
    console.log(results);
}
```

Good luck :)